# secure Kibana and elasticsearch using SSL / TLS

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, kibana

Thanks for taking the time to read this :)
My web app (grimoirelab) contains multiple services spun up using docker-compose which contains elasticsearch and kibana . Port 5601 (kibana) is open and accessible through the web.

I want to enable SSL / TLS in the Kibana container , i.e , change the URL from http to https

Kibana and Elasticsearch are both of Version : 6.8.6

I have very less experience in web security so would really appreciate any guidance on the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/ssl-tls.html) elasticsearch documentation for configuration of SSL and TLS, and it is available as free after 6.8 version.

Please check [Configuring SSL, TLS, and HTTPS to secure Elasticsearch, Kibana, Beats, and Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/blog/configuring-ssl-tls-and-https-to-secure-elasticsearch-kibana-beats-and-logstash) blog.

Please check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/configuring-tls-docker.html) documentation for how to setup SSL and TLS with Elasticsearch  Docker Container.